# Forbidden 403 Apache error on an Indico installation

Tags: python-2.7, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, indico

I installed Indico http://indico-software.org/ that is an open source tool for event organization, archival and collaboration on Ubuntu with this instructions https://indico.syntek.org/category/1/material/0/0.pdf, installation looks ok but when I try to open localhost/indico I get a forbidden 403 error.

I added this lines to the /etc/apache2/apach2.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/indico/htdocs/
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/pythonenv/BASELINE
WSGIPythonPath 
    /usr/local/pythonenv/indico12/lib/python2.7/sitepackages
WSGIPythonEggs /opt/indico/tmp/egg-cache 

<Directory /opt/indico/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
<Files indico.wsgi>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

This is my virtulhost file on /etc/apache2/sites-available/a2indico.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        LogLevel warn

     Alias /indico/images "/opt/indico/htdocs/images"
     Alias /indico/css "/opt/indico/htdocs/css"
     Alias /indico/js "/opt/indico/htdocs/js"
     Alias /indico/ihelp "/opt/indico/htdocs/ihelp"

     WSGIDaemonProcess WSGIDAEMON processes=32 threads=1 inactivity-
timeout=3600 maximumrequests=10000 python-
path=/usr/local/pythonenv/indico12/lib/python2.7/site-packages python-
eggs=/opt/indico/tmp/egg-cache

     WSGIScriptAlias /indico "/opt/indico/htdocs/indico.wsgi"

     <Directory "/opt/indico">
        WSGIProcessGroup WSGIDAEMON
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        AllowOverride None
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The chown for the /etc/apach2 and /opt/indico directorys are for www-data user.

Thank you very much for your help.

Plz give me some advise. =)

Answer (score 0):

Your probably not landing in that newly created virtualhost, it has no ServerName or ServerAlias.   `apachectl -S` will show you the other virtualhosts you have. Even after specifying a ServerName or ServerAlias here, you may need to modify your default (000-default) virtualhost as it may implicitly use your local systems name as a ServerNAme (ubuntu leaves it blank which can hide a later vhost!)

Comment: Tanks for your answer it was not that but thank you for your help and time.